# WCF Service enable tracing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

After two days of try and error and blind debugging, my web service still produces some error in certain cases and for now, I don't know why.
Therefor, I would like to enable tracing for the service in order to have at least a little feedback.

However, I tried a few addition to the web.config, but none ever produced a trace file, even if the service responded with an error.

So long, this is my web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"        type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
     </configSections>
     <connectionStrings>
     <...removed here... />
     </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TimeRecHomePage.Service.TimeService" behaviorConfiguration="TimeServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint name="webHttpBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" contract="TimeRecHomePage.Service.ITimeService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
        <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TimeServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
     </configuration>
```

I already looked up the configuration of the tracing and tested the entries for the web.config proposed e.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773026/how-to-debug-wcf-service-call-works-in-vs-but-not-in-iis), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) and also read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx).

As it is written in the documentation, that from Windows 8 on, you need privileged rights in order to trace, I also changed the application pool identity, without success though (the service runs on an Win 2012 R2 server).

What am I missing in order to enable and use tracing?
Thank you in advance for your efforts!

Comment: Is attach to WCF process not an option or occurs the fault only in production?

Comment: The fault only occurs in production. I already debugged locally in Visual Studio, where the error not occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two sections in your web.config, one is where the tracelisteners are configured and the diagnostics section in system.serviceModel.

#### system.diagnostics

Add the following section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
                 <add name="messages"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\temp\messages.svclog" />
          </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
    propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
              <add name="tracing"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\temp\tracing.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Notice the value of `initializeData` and make sure you add a path there where the application identity can write. A system wide tempfolder should be an option.

#### system.serviceModel diagniostics

Adapt your `system.serviceModel` nd add the diagnostics settings

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging 
         logEntireMessage="true" 
         logMalformedMessages="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
  <!-- your other stuff here -->
</system.serviceModel>
```

#### Test your settings

With the above config your logifiles should be created and the `tracing.scvlog` should show entries when the service is started or when you request the wsdl for your service. It also holds any exceptions and stacktraces that occur.